# else statement doesn't work in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello all I have table with products and prices for them. All I am trying to do is to show minimum  price of each product and if it isn't present in price table show product with price null Here is a query I wrote

```
SELECT 
t15_catalogue_line.T15_GROUP, sc_products.product_code,sc_products.unic, 
sc_products.name_ru, UPPER(TRIM(sc_products.brief_description_ru)) AS 
brief_description_ru, sc_products.suupplier, price.Price, 
sc_group_discounts.`action`, sc_group_discounts.procent,
sc_products.productID, price.in_stock, price.supplier, t10_item.T10_ITEM, 
t10_item.unic, t10_item.T10_DESC, t10_item.T10_IMG, t10_item.T10_ITEM_GROUP, 
t10_item.T10_FIELD1, t10_item.T10_FIELD2, t10_item.T10_FIELD3, 
t10_item.T10_FIELD4, t10_item.T10_FIELD5, t10_item.T10_FIELD6, 
t10_item.T10_FIELD7, t10_item.T10_FIELD8, t10_item.T10_FIELD9, 
t10_item.T10_FIELD10, t10_item.T10_FIELD11, t14_item_fields.T14_ITEM_GROUP, 
t14_item_fields.T14_FIELD, t14_item_fields.T14_NAME, 
t14_item_fields.T14_UNIT, t14_item_fields.T14_SEARCH 
FROM sc_products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t15_catalogue_line ON (sc_products.unic = t15_catalogue_line.unic) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN price ON (sc_products.product_code = price.item) AND (sc_products.suupplier = price.postavchik)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sc_group_discounts ON (sc_products.item_group = sc_group_discounts.item_group)
LEFT OUTER JOIN t10_item ON (sc_products.unic = t10_item.unic and sc_products.CatText=t10_item.CatText)
LEFT OUTER JOIN t14_item_fields ON (t10_item.T10_ITEM_GROUP = t14_item_fields.T14_ITEM_GROUP) 
WHERE sc_products.CatText = 'bearing' 
AND t15_catalogue_line.T15_CARTYPE = '42769' 
AND t15_catalogue_line.T15_GROUP = '546678' and sc_products.unic is not null and sc_products. unic!='' and 
CASE WHEN price.Price is null then price.Price is null else price.Price=(SELECT 
MIN(price.Price) from price where price.unic=sc_products.unic 
AND price.CatText='bearing') end 
GROUP BY sc_products.unic 
ORDER by isnull (price.Price),price.Price ASC
```

Now it shows only those with price null else statement didn't work.

Comment: Please format the query

Answer (score 0):

In your `case` you must use `THEN NULL`, not `THEN price.Price IS NULL`:

```
 AND CASE
        WHEN price.Price IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE
           (
                SELECT
                    MIN(price.Price)
                FROM
                    price
                WHERE
                    price.unic = sc_products.unic
                AND price.CatText = 'bearing'
            )
    END
```

Instead of the end case you should use an `AND` condition, like this:

```
AND (    ( price.CatText = 'bearing' AND  price.unic = sc_products.unic) 
      OR ( price.CatText = 'bearing' AND  price.unic is numm)  )
```

and an eventually select of min(your_value)  should be in select clause and not in where.

Comment: Thank you very much but now it shows only those products with price. Is there any way to show them all?

Comment: Thank you but sadly result is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry but  i have take a more deep look at you query and your AND CASE don't make sense to me beacuse you don't test any conditition ... what the meaning of this and CASE .. try explain ...please

Comment: Ye you are right There is a table with price that contains products with same code but different prices i have to select minimal price for each product and show user all without prices too. That product that is without price don't exit in price table.

Comment: Thank you but now it doesn't show those with price.

Comment: Then you must  evaluate you logic .. the and case was wrong and my are only suggestion because i don't know your logic .. need

Answer (score 0):

The other answer was close... You will probably need to do this via an additional LEFT-JOIN to what your ELSE sub-select is...

LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT
           price.unic,
           MIN(price.Price) as minprice
        FROM
           price
        WHERE
           price.CatText = 'bearing'
        group by
           price.unic ) ByUnic
   ON sc_products.unic = ByUnic.unic

and then INSTEAD of your case/when WHERE clause, remove it.  Change the field selection property getting your price from... price.price to:

```
  COALESCE( price.Price, ByUnic.minPrice ) as Price
```

This will return the price.price field first.  If that is null, then it returns the value from the left-join table ByUnic, minPrice result IF it is exists, otherwise still remains as null.  If you want the minimum price first before the Price.Price, just swap the field order such as

```
  COALESCE( ByUnic.minPrice, price.Price ) as Price
```